# WCF - Error: The message version of the outgoing message (Soap12 (http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope)

Tags: wcf, .net-3.5

1) I have WCF service deployed on local IIS 5.1:

Interface:

```
[OperationContract(Action = Service.RequestAction, ReplyAction = Service.ReplyAction)]
Message SetData(Message requestXml);
```

Implementation:

```
public const string ReplyAction = "http://localhost/AsurReceiveData/Message_ReplyAction";
public const string RequestAction = "http://localhost/AsurReceiveData/Message_RequestAction";

public Message SetData(Message requestXml)
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(@"E:\Projekti\WCF\Parus\AsurReplicData\Parus\Body.xml"))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(requestXml.ToString());
    }
    Message response = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Default, ReplyAction, requestXml.ToString());

    return response;
}
```

Web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
      <add prefix="http://localhost:80/"/>
    </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
  </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="Parus.ServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="http://localhost/AsurReceiveData/Service.svc"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        <MyInspector />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="Parus.ServiceBehavior" name="Parus.Service">
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/AsurReceiveData/Service.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Parus.IService">
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
  </services>
  <extensions>
    <behaviorExtensions>
      <add name="MyInspector" type="Parus.MessageInspectorExtension, Parus, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
    </behaviorExtensions>
  </extensions>
</system.serviceModel>
```

2) The client side looks as following:

```
ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
string RequestAction = "http://localhost/AsurReceiveData/Message_RequestAction";
Message request = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Default, RequestAction, "Test message");
Message reply = client.SetData(request);
```

Web.config:

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
 openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
 allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
 maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
 messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
 useDefaultWebProxy="true">
 <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
  maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
 <security mode="None">
  <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
   realm="" />
  <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
 </security>
</binding>
<endpoint address="http://localhost/AsurReceiveData/Service.svc"
  binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
  contract="ServiceReference.IService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
```

When I run the client, the following error message comes up:

> The message version of the outgoing message (Soap12 (http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope) Addressing10 (http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing)) does not match that of the encoder (Soap11 (http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/) AddressingNone (http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none)). Make sure the binding is configured with the same version as the message.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have version mismatch between in your client and server. Make sure you are using:

1. Same MessageVersion
2. Same AddressinVersion
3. Same Encoding

Comment: I know that but where exactly should I set them, in web.config files or in code and what should I set?

Comment: The error message is coming on client side and I've already tried to set different options in message creation method but nothing helps.